# Downloading images and videos from WCF service IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, wcf, uiimageview, uiimage

I am new to web services and I have searched it but I couldn't find any documents about it. Is there any way to download *images* and *videos* from *WCF Service* and save the my app's document files? or do I need to use different way for download?

Thanks for your advice and interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AFNetWorking: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

This is a sample how I download files from a WCF:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *reqeust = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:{url}]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:reqeust];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:{path_on_disk} append:NO];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        //Download progress    
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //Download failed
    }];

[operation start]
```